# How Can I Send an Authentication Token to Expressjs from React with Firebase Auth

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, express, firebase-authentication

Hi, I am trying to create a project with authentication with React, Express, and Firebase. In the process of creating the authentication, I don't know why this way of sending the auth token doesn't work for me

###### `httpClient.js` file

```
import axios from 'axios'
import { auth } from '../firebase/firebase'

var config = {
   baseURL: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/",
   timeout: 5000,
}
auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
   user.getIdToken(true)
      .then((token) => {
         // I have tried this too, unfortunately same results
         // axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`

         config.headers = {
            authorization: token
         }
      })
      .catch(err => {
         console.log(err)
      })
})

console.log(config)
export default axios.create(config)
```

When I check the value of the config in the console, this is what I get:

```
      {
         "baseURL": "http://127.0.0.1:5000/",
         "timeout": 5000,
         "headers": {
             "authorization": "##AUTH TOKEN HERE##"
         }
     }
```

However when I checked my `req.headers` in my express app, this is what I get:

```
      {
         host: '127.0.0.1:5000',
         connection: 'keep-alive',
         'sec-ch-ua': '"Chromium";v="92", " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="92"',
         accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
         'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
         'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.107 Safari/537.36',      
         origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
         'sec-fetch-site': 'cross-site',
         'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
         'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
         referer: 'http://localhost:3000/',
         'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
         'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
         'if-none-match': 'W/"770-rnaTbTjcnfFuL5mkxjLb7fT1wEU"'
       }
```

If there's any way to send an auth token to the backend with the tools that I use please let me know. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that the console log statement you show here is what is actually printing the output?  I would expect that it wouldn't show the auth header at all.  The Firebase APIs are asynchronous and complete after the module is loaded, which means you're exporting an axios object that doesn't use the a config that was modified from its original value.

Comment: Hi @DougStevenson, that's what I thought so. I'm just thinking right now where else I can configure my config for my axios object.

Comment: If you have a new question, I suggest asking it separately.  Explain the new problem and show what you tried that doesn't work the way you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Doug mentioned, Firebase APIs are asynchronous so there's a high chance of your API request being ran before the `onAuthStateChanged` get's the ID Token. Instead I would recommend to get the ID Token in the function which calls your API as follows:

```js
asnyc function callMyAPI() {
  const token = await firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken()
  // Write Axios Request here
  // Add the authorization header here
}
```